# C++ Month, day, and year validation

Tags: c++, date

I'm currently working on a project for my intro to C++ programming class. The project asks a user to enter a date using mm/dd/yyyy format. Based on the information given, the program then has to determine if the date is valid or invalid, then displays a response to that. I'm facing the problem currently where everything is coming out reading "Good date!" I'm not sure where the problem is. Any help is appreciated. If you could help point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void getDate(int *month, int *day, int *year);
int checkDate(int month, int day, int year);
void displayMessage(int status);

int main()
{
    int month, day, year;
    int s = 0;

    getDate(&month, &day, &year);
    do
    {
        checkDate(month, day, year);
        displayMessage(s);
        getDate(&month, &day, &year);
    } 
    while (_getch() != EOF);
}

void getDate(int *month, int *day, int *year)
{
    char fill;
    fill = '/';
    cout << "Enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy form: ";
    cin >> *month;
    if (cin.get() != '/')
    {
        cout << "expected /" << endl;
    }
    cin >> *day;
    if (cin.get() != '/')
    {
        cout << "expected /" << endl;
    }
    cin >> *year;
    cout << *month << fill << *day << fill << *year << endl;
};

int checkDate(int month, int day, int year)
{
    if ((month = 1) || (month = 3) || (month = 5) || (month = 7) ||
        (month = 8) || (month = 10) || (month = 12))
    {
        day <= 31;
    }
    else if ((month = 4) || (month = 6) || (month = 9) || (month = 11))
    {
        day <= 30;
    }
    else if ((month = 2) && (year % 4 == 0))
    {
    day <= 29;
    }
    else if ((month = 2) && (year % 4 != 0))
    {
        day <= 28;
    };
    int status = 0;
    if ((year < 999) || (year > 10000))
    {
        status == 1;
    }
    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12))
    {
        status == 2;
    }
    else if ((day < 1) || (day > 31))
    {
        status == 3;
    }
    else if ((day < 1) || (day > 30))
    {
        status == 4;
    }
    else if ((day < 1) || (day > 29))
    {
        status == 5;
    }
    else if ((day < 1) || (day > 28))
    {
        status == 6;
    }
    return status;
};

void displayMessage(int status)
{
    if (status == 0)
    {
        cout << "Good date!" << endl;
    }
    if (status == 1)
    {
        cout << "Bad year" << endl;
    }
    if (status == 2)
    {
        cout << "Bad month" << endl;
    }
    if (status == 3)
    {
        cout << "Bad day. Not 1-31" << endl;
    }
    if (status == 4)
    {
        cout << "Bad day, not 1-30" << endl;
    }
    if (status == 5)
    {
        cout << "Bad day, not 1-29" << endl;
    }
    if (status == 6)
    {
        cout << "Bad day, not 1-28" << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Why does checkDate() have a return value if it is always discarded? Why have a variable s in main() that is never altered?

Comment: You never assign `s` to anything, so it stays at its initial value (`0`).

Comment: @JonathanPotter how would I link it to `status` in `displayMessage`? That is what I'm confused about. That's why `s` is there because I'm unsure how to fill `displayMessage(___)` in the do loop.

Comment: `s = checkDate(month, day, year);`

Comment: Also, your `checkDate` function doesn't actually return anything anyway, because all your assignments are actually equality tests. e.g. `status == 4;` should be `status = 4;`

Comment: And what is it you expect `day <= 31;` to do? Your code is very odd.

Comment: What I anticipated `day <= 31` to do is set all of those months in the `if` statement to only have a maximum of 31 days. There has to be a checker to make sure the date in the month is valid. @JonathanPotter

Comment: Is that the wrong way of setting that? @JonathanPotter Like I said, this is my first time using C++ and I have a professor that doesn't explain stuff all that well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There are a couple of issues here,  but the most obvious one is in `main()`:

```
int s=0; 
...
    checkDate(month, day, year);   // you don't store the status
    displayMessage(s);             // so s will always be 0 ! So good date !
```

You have to correct this:

```
    s=checkDate(month, day, year); // store the result of the check        
    displayMessage(s);             // and take it to display the message
```

2) Then in `checkDate()`, you mixup `=` and `==`.  `=` changes the value of the variable to its left.  `==` just makes a comparison but store nothing.  When correcting/adjusting, without any optimisation, your code should look like:

```
int checkDate(int month, int day, int year)
{
    int status=0; 

    if ((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 ||
        month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && ( day>31 || day<1) )
    {
        status = 3; 
    }
    else if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day>30 || day<1) )
    {
        status = 4; 
    }
    else if ((month == 2) && (year % 4 == 0) && (day>29 || day<1))
    {
        status = 5; 
    }
    else if ((month == 2) && (year % 4 != 0) && (day>28 || day<1) )
    {
        status = 6; 
    }
    else if ((year < 999) || (year > 10000))
    {
        status = 1;
    }
    if ((month < 1) || (month > 12))
    {
        status = 2;
    }
    return status;
};
```

3) After this, you should improve the input function, because:

- it doesn't cope with invalid separators.  If '/' are missing, an error message is displayed, but you continue the input as if everything was fine.
- it doesn't cope with invalid (i.e.non numeric) input.  If user enters XI/1/2016 for example,  your input will fail.

So keep in mind that `(cin>>xxx)` is an expression that you could use in an `if` and is true if everything was read correctly.  Also be aware that [`cin.clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) clears error flags that blocks input after a failure.

Comment: Makes sense.. Stupid I didn't see that. How would I link the values of month, day, year to their values assigned by the user input? @Christophe

Comment: @JustinFarr I've completed my answer with a couple of systematic  issues in checkDate().

Comment: @JustinFarr you already did the link for the dates components, because you use pointers in the input function, so that the values are directly written in the variables in main().

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed ! I missed to correct one of the =. Thanks for pointing it out so nicely ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You also could make use of the function `mktime()`.

It tries to convert a given tm struct into a correct date. If the comparison of the individual members of the struct subsequently shows equality for all members, the given tm struct contained a valid date.

```
bool CBorrow::validateDate(tm * timestruct)
{
    struct tm copy;
    copy.tm_sec = timestruct->tm_sec;
    copy.tm_min = timestruct->tm_min;
    copy.tm_hour = timestruct->tm_hour;
    copy.tm_mday = timestruct->tm_mday;
    copy.tm_mon = timestruct->tm_mon;
    copy.tm_year = timestruct->tm_year;
    copy.tm_wday = timestruct->tm_wday;
    copy.tm_yday = timestruct->tm_yday;
    copy.tm_isdst = timestruct->tm_isdst;

    time_t res = mktime(&copy);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (copy.tm_mday != timestruct->tm_mday
     || copy.tm_mon != timestruct->tm_mon
     || copy.tm_year != timestruct->tm_year)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void
displayMessage(std::chrono::year_month_day ymd)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    if (!ymd.year().ok())
    {
        cout << "Bad year\n";
        return;
    }
    if (!ymd.month().ok())
    {
        cout << "Bad month\n";
        return;
    }
    if (!ymd.ok())
    {
        cout << "Bad day, not 1-" << (ymd.year()/ymd.month()/last).day() << '\n';
        return;
    }
    cout << "Good date!\n";
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    displayMessage(29d/2/1900);
}
```

Output:

```
Bad day, not 1-28
```

(1900 was *not* a leap year)

Comment: In order for the above code to compile on my compilers - `Apple clang++ 14` and `g++-12 (Homebrew GCC)` - with `-std=c++20`, I have to wrap `(ymd.year()/ymd.month()/last).day()` with `static_cast<unsigned>()`. That is, change the line to `cout << "Bad day, not 1-" << static_cast<unsigned>((ymd.year()/ymd.month()/last).day()) << '\n';`. @Howard do you have any comments here?

Comment: It sounds like the C++20 chrono implementation is not complete in libc++ nor libstdc++.  Here is the spec for the `day` streaming operator in C++20: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal.day.nonmembers#7.  Your workaround for the incomplete implementation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact and stripped checkDate (replace uppercase return by value)

```
int checkDate(int day, int month, int year) {
    if(day < 1 || day > 31) {
        return BADVALUE;
    } else if(month < 1 || month > 12) {
        return BADVALUE;
    } else if (year < MINYEAR || year > MAXYEAR) {
        return YEAROUTRANGE;
    }

    if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day == 31) {
        return BADMONTHDAY; 
    } else if ((month == 2) && (year % 4 == 0) && day > 29) {
        return BADMONTHYEAR;

    } else if ((month == 2) && (year % 4 != 0) && day > 28) {
        return BADMONTHYEAR; 
    }
    return GOOD;
}
```

Comment: This function validates 29 Feb 1900 as a valid date, which is wrong. Century years are leap years only when they are divisible by 400. Since 1900 is not divisible by 400, 29 Feb 1900 is not a valid date. This check is needed in this function

Comment: `bool centuryYearFlag = (year % 400 == 0 ? true : false);
if (day == 29 && month == 2 && !centuryYearFlag)
   return BADVALUE`

Answer (score 0):

Can this also be achieved by a regular expression?

I know there are many drawbacks in this approach, but still may be considered:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using std::regex;
using std::regex_match;
using std::string;

// for ddmmyy
regex ddmmyy("^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))\\d{2}$");

/* 
   for dd/mm/yy https://regex101.com/r/IqPLBJ/1
   for dd/mm/yyyy - could start from \\d{4}$ instead of \\d{2}$ bearing 0000-case in mind
*/
regex slashed_ddmmyy("^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])\/(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))\/\\d{2}$"); 

string f1 = "111223";
bool res = regex_match(f1,ddmmyy); // true

f1 = "112223";
res = regex_match(f1,ddmmyy); // false

res = regex_match(f1, slashed_ddmmyy); // false, no slashes
```